# Get an email notification when my cron fails with non zero exit code - Crontab

Tags: cron

I have scheduled a script `take_backup.sh` in crontab like so

```
00 19 * * * bash /home/test/take_backup.sh > /home/test/backup.log 2>&1 || mail -s "Backup failed, check attached logs" someone@gmail.com < /home/test/backup.log
```

The requirement is to only send an email notification with the logs attached when the cron fails with a non zero exit code. I have set up logs and exit codes in the script to provide more details in `backup.log`. However, when this cron fails, I do not receive any notification.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the "mail" part succeeds then the cron job has succeeded (and thus the code is zero)

```
 00 19 * * * bash /home/test/take_backup.sh > /home/test/backup.log 2>&1 || ( mail -s "Backup failed, check attached logs" someone@gmail.com < /home/test/backup.log && false )
```

Comment: I require the notification when the cron fails though, how do I change the command for that?